# Integration ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity with Local AD (not Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

i can't find way to integrate Identity with Local Active Directory (not Azure). Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Good question.  This might help: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/authenticating-to-active-directory-federation-services-adfs-2019-with-net-core-3-1-b0bf012fc183

Answer (score 1):

Your application will need to connect to an [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) / [OpenIdConnect](https://openid.net/connect/) system, and that system will federate access into your local AD. This is a specialist area, and relatively complicated, but it is essential for well designed modern systems.

Both [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) (a complete system) and [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (a framework) support this.

Take a look at [this deep dive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJYy6Aq-PJ8) on how to integrate LDAP users with KeyCloak (12m46s in is where the presenter talks about LDAP integration).

Comment: I'm surprised Microsoft doesn't make it easier to integrate [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with "On-Premises Active Directory".  But apparently they don't.  Thank you for an excellent response, suggesting a good, open source alternative,